# Get from AXLE to TIZZ

Tags: wordplay

This is a pretty common game, where you must change one letter at a time from a word to get to another word. My dad created an algorithm to find some of the hardest of these puzzles.

**RULES:**

- You can only change one letter at a time
- After each letter change the resulting letters must be a word
- An additional challenge is to get there with 17 or under steps

**Example:**

From Break to Trend:

Break - Bread - Tread - Trend

Comment: Partial answers are encouraged!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way... and for those who don't want to see the spoiler it's less than 17 words

> axle ayle syle sile size sizz tizz

Incidentally, I think it's more interesting to go from BLACK to WHITE, say (and in far fewer moves - say 7 or 'less').

Comment: Tizz/Tizzy is a word. A noun actually: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tizzy

Comment: Fair enough. getting myself all in a tizz for no reason,

Comment: Well done! I was having a lot of trouble solving this one.

Answer (score 3):

Strawberry’s solution contains a lot of words I’ve never heard of. I made my own, but it’s a lot longer:

> axle able ably ally alls alms aims dims dime dame fame fume fuze fuzz fizz tizz

Comment: “Your alls” means “everything you own”: See the [citation on the second definition here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all#Noun).

Answer (score 1):

Using [TWL06](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_Tournament_and_Club_Word_List#References) (which doesn't contain "tizz") the best I could do is

> axle able ably ally alls ails fils file rile rale raze razz jazz jizz tizz

14 steps.